# How can learn Opencart easily

Tags: opencart

Hi am new in **Opencart**, but i know how to install and how to manage default **Opencart**.

I want to know how to customize the **Opencart** like

1. How to create page **(eg:my_account.tpl)**
2. How to display customer details in this page.
3. How to create button in page1.tpl and redirected to my_account.tpl

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

For Learning customization you first need to learn PHP with some basic knowledge of HTML,CSS and Javascript and then you have to learn about Opencart framework. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru).

Now I will answer on the points you have raised.

1. You can create page by first creating controller in catalog/controller/account folder, then you need to define the function inside controller class and then call the response function that loads the html from view. Now you need to have my_account.tpl file inside catalog/view/theme/default/template/account folder.
2. For displaying customer details you can use these as reference 
   CUSTOMER

   $this->customer->isLogged() - check if customer is logged in

   $this->customer->getId() - get the database entry id for the current 
   customer (integer)

   $this->customer->getFirstName() - get customer first name

   $this->customer->getLastName() - get customer last name

   $this->customer->getEmail() - get customer email

   $this->customer->getTelephone() - get customer telephone number

   $this->customer->getFax() - get customer fax number

   $this->customer->getNewsletter() - get customer newsletter status

   $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId() - get customer group id

   $this->customer->getAddressId() - get customer default address id (maps to 
   the address database field)

these should be declared in controller and then passed to view.
 3. For adding link to redirect to any other page on button you can use the link function by opencart framework

```
$this->url->link('folder/file/function')
```

for example you created a new page myaccount.php and your main function is index.php where you load the page , you can refer this by creating link

```
$this->url->link('account/myaccount')
```

You must understand how opencart framework works to take hint from above mentioned answers and  make it work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion bro. Actually now i have well knowledge in `Opencart`.